# Iphone Keyboard showing on all Applications

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

Iphone 4s application Keyboard Problem. In main menu Keyboard is also showing not hiding. when slide to search`enter code here` after back slide to applications they also showing on applications.

Comment: set delegates for textfield & text view

Answer (score 2):

you have to **resign first responder** from TextField or search bar before moving

Answer (score 0):

Try this using following two options,
In textDidChange delegate of UISearchBar, u can check the characters in the search bar, if character length is 0 then u can resign the keyboard.
otherwise, you can add one more button above the keyboard or anywhere as you want on view and on that button click resign the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want to hide keyboard, then in action in which you want to hide keyboard write below code

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

let me know is it working or not!!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

use `<UItextfieldDelegate>` in your .h file. Then make wiring with fileowner in nib file.

write in .m file

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
 return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this task when you are moving form your view

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```